# Heatmap based on gene expression trend

Tags: r, clustering, dendrogram, heatmap

Can anybody guide me on the R code for the following problem?

My data contains expression values of Genes A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, and I in a time course study for two time steps, 48 and 72 hours, with and without a treatment.

The dummy data looks like this:

```
Gene Names      Fold change 48h              Fold change 72h
A               1.2                          4.6
B               1.2                          1.2
C               2.3                          1.4 
...             ...                          ...
```

Expression values of Genes A,B and C show continually increasing trend.
Expression values of Genes D,E and F remained approximately same for the two time points. Genes G, H and I had higher expression in 48h but decreased in 72 hour time point.

How can I cluster these “three” groups of genes based on the criteria described above?

I can create a `heatmap` using `hclust` etc.

Comment: Is does not seem right. You already know your clusters and would like to see code implementing a method that returns the groups you want? It should be the other way round: Given your data, what are the groups that a clustering algorithm can identify?

Comment: Questions asking for code help are generally off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible data structure...
something like this?

```
df <- data_frame(
  Gene = rep(letters[1:8], times = 2),
  Timestep = c(rep('48h', times = 8), rep('72h', times = 8)),
  Expression = rnorm(n = 16)
)
```

what about the treatment vs no treatment group?

---

Here is something to start with:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12345)
gene_data <- spread(df, key = Timestep, value = Expression)

# Get cluster membership for each row (gene)
clusters <- kmeans(gene_data[,2:3], 3, nstart = 20)

# Combine cluster membership with gene_data
gene_clusters <- cbind(gene_data, cluster = clusters$cluster)

# Plot clusters
gene_clusters %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `48h`, y = `72h`, col = cluster)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```